# Error de DLL en Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Al tratar de correr el proyecto me tira estos errores
[image: Errores]
Pero si al seleccionar cualquiera me manda a este DLL

[image: DLL]

Buscando en Google el nombre del mismo vi que tiene que ver con NuGet y
al abrir la Package Menager Console de NuGet encontre el siguiente mensaje

> Package Manager Console Host Version 2.12.0.817
>
> Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.
>
> The 'System.Net.Primitives 4.0.10' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'.
>
> PM>

y bueno e tratado de actualizarlo por este mismo medio y por la asistente visual pero no he tenido exito si alguien sabe como se le agradece los comandos que he usados son los siguientes

```
PM> Install-Package NuGet.VisualStudio -Version 3.5.0
```

y he probado varias verciones todas te dicen que se instala pero cuando pruebo aun reiniciando el visual studio aun me aparecen los errores que presento al comienzo.

Comment: mmm.. pero nuget es el sistema que se usa para traerte esos paquetes.. no tiene nada que ver con la ejecucion de tu programa.. pero nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras tratar de resolverlo y probar todos los cambios commit por commit, solo fue necesario desinstalar mi Visual Studio junto con todos sus componentes y volverlo a instalar y funciono mi proyecto sin ningun problema.